# C++ program elapse time

Tags: c++

I want to find running time of a program (not CPU time). I have written a c++ code as follows.

```
time_t start,end;
time (&start);
//code
time (&end);
double dif = difftime (end,start);
cout << dif ;
```

I got a output for particular instance as 2. what does this means? How can I get more accurate measure for elapse time (wall clock time)

Comment: [difftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) returns elapsed seconds.

Comment: I have changed the question

Comment: To answer your updated question: there are various ways, but `boost::timer` is probably the simplest and most portable. See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html